# webpack - loading from different node_modules for files in different folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack

If I have a folder structure like this

```
root
|
|-src
| |-components
|
|-otherSrc
| |-components
|   |-sub_components
| |-node_modules
|
|-node_modules
```

Is it possible to load libraries referenced in **root/src/components/*.js***
from **root/node_modules** and for **root/othersrc/components/.js** from **root/othersrc/node_modules** (or root/othersrc/components/sub_components/*.js from root/othersrc/node_modules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `node_modules` will be scanned only relative to the current directory going up to the root, so your deeply nested directories won't be searched for as candidates for resolving packages.

You can either install all the dependencies somewhere in the ancestry (e.g. `/node_modules`) or configure [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) and use absolute imports or you'll have to specify relative paths in the packages in `node_modules` that will only work on your computer.

These approaches leave you at a disadvantage because it's hard to move your sources between machines, ensure that the correct dependencies are resolved and that they can be kept up-to-date. If you really want modularize your application into "components" that have their own dependencies and can be independently redistributed and maintained from the rest of your sources, then you might want to look into the [monorepository pattern](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/doc/design/monorepo.md).